# Hide one bootstrap table header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

My table header is looking like this:-

```html
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="missed-entries">
   <div class="container">
      <div class="panel panel-info" style="margin-top:24px;">
         <div class="panel-heading"> <h3 class="panel-title">Info</h3> </div>
         <div class="panel-body">blahh</div>
      </div>
      <table id="scale_missed_entries" data-toggle="table" data-pagination="true" >
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th id="hidethis" data-field="product_id">ID</th>                           
               <th data-field="product_weight">Weight</th>
               <th data-field="product_added_date">Added date</th>
               <th data-field="button">Image</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
      </table>
   </div>
</div>
```

I want to full hide this entire ID column with the id="hidethis".

What I tried :

```
<th id="hidethis" data-field="product_id" style="display:none;">ID</th>
```

this didn't do anything, I think that css cannot be used like that in a th.

```
$('hidethis').hide();
```

No impact with that jquery also.

```
$('td:nth-child(2),th:nth-child(2)').hide();
```

The closest success I had with this, but that only hidden my Image th, but all my buttons remained there.

I will also put a picture:

[image]

I want to full hide all of the marked with red.

Comment: Can you provide the code that makes the table ?

Comment: Apply a same class on that row and it's values and hide them.

Comment: I added the insert code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i commented also apply a same class to `th` and there corresponding values `<td>` and hide them. it will work.

```js
$('.hidethis').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="missed-entries">
<div class="container">
 <div class="panel panel-info" style="margin-top:24px;"><div class="panel-heading"> <h3 class="panel-title">Info</h3> </div><div class="panel-body">blahh</div></div>
  <table id="scale_missed_entries" data-toggle="table" data-pagination="true" >
   <thead>
    <tr>
     <th class="hidethis" data-field="product_id">ID</th>                           
     <th data-field="product_weight">Weight</th>
     <th data-field="product_added_date">Added date</th>
     <th data-field="button">Image</th>
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td class="hidethis" data-field="product_id">112</td>                           
     <td data-field="product_weight">51</td>
     <td data-field="product_added_date">2017-10-11</td>
     <td data-field="button">hi1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td class="hidethis" data-field="product_id">111</td>                           
     <td data-field="product_weight">50</td>
     <td data-field="product_added_date">2017-10-10</td>
     <td data-field="button">hi</td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
 </div>
</div>
```

***Note:- without jquery also you can now hide then through css:-***

```
.hidethis{
  display:none; // or visibility:hidden;
}
```

Comment: @TatuBogdan  glad to help you;:):)

Answer (score 3):

I've tried to make my code as easy as possible and also included some comments.

I would consider using a class instead of an id though. :)

```js
// Save index (position) of th
const cellIndex = $('#hidethis').index();

// Hide th first
$('#hidethis').hide();

// Iterate over each table row
$('#scale_missed_entries tbody tr').each(function () {

  // Select the cell with same index (position) as the table header
  const cell = $(this).children('td').get(cellIndex);
  
  // Hide 'em
  $(cell).hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="missed-entries">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="panel panel-info" style="margin-top:24px;">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Info</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">blahh</div>
    </div>
    <table id="scale_missed_entries" data-toggle="table" data-pagination="true">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th id="hidethis" data-field="product_id">ID</th>
          <th data-field="product_weight">Weight</th>
          <th data-field="product_added_date">Added date</th>
          <th data-field="button">Image</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply using `CSS`

```css
[data-field="product_id"] {
  display: none;
}

tr td:nth-of-type(1) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="missed-entries">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="panel panel-info" style="margin-top:24px;">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Info</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">blahh</div>
    </div>
    <table id="scale_missed_entries" data-toggle="table" data-pagination="true">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th id="hidethis" data-field="product_id">ID</th>
          <th data-field="product_weight">Weight</th>
          <th data-field="product_added_date">Added date</th>
          <th data-field="button">Image</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1
          </td>
          <td>10
          </td>
          <td>100
          </td>
          <td>1000
          </td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use this

```
#scale_missed_entries th:nth-child(1) {
display: none;
}
```

**edit based on the coment**

To hide entire column use this--

```
#hidethis{
display:none;
}
```

```css
 #myTable th:nth-child(1) {
    display: none;
       }
       
 #hidethis{
 display:none;
 }
```

```html
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="missed-entries">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="panel panel-info" style="margin-top:24px;"><div class="panel-heading"> <h3 class="panel-title">Info</h3> </div><div class="panel-body">blahh</div></div>
                        <table id="scale_missed_entries" data-toggle="table" data-pagination="true">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th id="hidethis" data-field="product_id">ID</th>
          <th data-field="product_weight">Weight</th>
          <th data-field="product_added_date">Added date</th>
          <th data-field="button">Image</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td id="hidethis">1
          </td>
          <td>10
          </td>
          <td>100
          </td>
          <td>1000
          </td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add:

> `#hidethis { display: none; }`

to your css:

```css
#hidethis {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="missed-entries">
  <div class="container">
      <div class="panel panel-info" style="margin-top:24px;">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h3 class="panel-title">Info</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">blahh</div>
      </div>
      <table id="scale_missed_entries"
             data-toggle="table"
             data-pagination="true">
        <thead>
          <tr>
             <th id="hidethis" data-field="product_id">ID</th>                    <th data-field="product_weight">Weight</th>
               <th data-field="product_added_date">Added date</th>
               <th data-field="button">Image</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
      </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps.